# DublinCore/Prism Namespaces/prefixes

Tags: xml, xslt

Have an xslt that needs to transforms elements from `<old>` to DublinCore or Prism namespaces (i.e. `dc:XXX` or `prism:XXX`). I tried to add a namespace prefix but still no luck. Example below is swapping "PMISSN" to "prism:issn"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     xmlns:pam="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/pam/2.2/" 
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.2/" 
    xmlns:pim="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/pim/2.2/" 
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
    xmlns:prl="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prl/2.1/" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  

xmlns:pur="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prismusagerights/2.1/" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PARA">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@PARA">
    <xsl:attribute name="p">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PMISSN">
    <prism:issn>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </prism:issn>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@PMISSN">
    <xsl:attribute name="prism:issn">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is an example of the file I wish to transform:

```
<CNVOUTPUT>
<ACTCD>A</ACTCD><TXTAVAIL>STORED</TXTAVAIL><TXTRIGHTS>YES</TXTRIGHTS><TPGAVAIL>NOT STORED</TPGAVAIL><TPGRIGHTS>NO</TPGRIGHTS><FPIAVAIL>STORED</FPIAVAIL><FPIRIGHTS>NO</FPIRIGHTS><PMINFO><PMID>17549</PMID><PMTTL><PTTL>Mag's</PTTL></PMTTL><PMQUAL>Toronto</PMQUAL><PMJCD>GMAC</PMJCD><PMISSN>00249262</PMISSN>

<PMCODEN>MCNMBC</PMCODEN><PMSTYP><PSCD>2</PSCD><PSDES>PERIODICAL</PSDES></PMSTYP></PMINFO><PCINFO><PCDATE><PCNDATE>19920127</PCNDATE><PCADATE>Jan 27, 1992</PCADATE></PCDATE><STDCITE><PCVOL>105</PCVOL><PCISSU>4</PCISSU></STDCITE></PCINFO><DOCINFO><DOCID>1703718</DOCID><CPR>Copyright Maclean Hunter Consumer Publications Jan 27, 1992</CPR><DTTL><TTL>Public Remarks on a Private Matter</TTL></DTTL><DCITE><PGC>1</PGC><SP>9</SP><DOCL>English</DOCL><DPG>9</DPG><XID>CBCAMCLE2678804</XID></DCITE><AUS><AU><AUNAME>Amiel, Barbara</AUNAME></AU></AUS><DOCTY>Commentary</DOCTY></DOCINFO><TEXT><TXT><PARA>No Text Available.</PARA></TXT></TEXT><IDX><ITY>General Subject Terms</ITY><ITM><DTY>General Subject Term</DTY><DTA>Journalism</DTA></ITM><ITM><DTY>General Subject Term</DTY><DTA>Journalistic ethics</DTA></ITM><ITY>Classification Codes</ITY><ITM><DTY>Classification Code</DTY><DTA>9172</DTA></ITM><ITM><DTY>Classification Expansion</DTY><DTA>Canada</DTA></ITM></IDX><ABS><SABS><PARA>A woman discusses her run-ins with with Canadian media.  Making matters more complicated is the fact that she is also a journalist.  Other journalists started writing about her past relationships.  She attributes the controversy to her success in the field.</PARA></SABS></ABS>
</CNVOUTPUT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a bug in your code. All the namespaces should be declared as attributes of the root element `xsl:stylesheet`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:pam="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/pam/2.2/" 
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.2/" 
    xmlns:pim="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/pim/2.2/" 
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
    xmlns:prl="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prl/2.1/" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  
    xmlns:pur="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prismusagerights/2.1/" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="dc pur rdf prl dcterms pim prism xhtml pam">
```

You can see it works fine here: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtc/1

To remove unneeded namespace declarations from your code, `exclude-result-prefixes` should be used. It lists all prefixes to be excluded.

P.S. There is a shorter XSLT 2.0 alternative `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"`

### UPDATE

If you want just two namespace declarations in the root element instead of each separate element that has a namespace, this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.2/" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

You can see the result here: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtc/4

Comment: Lagvian- thank you- it runs, but adds a pile of namespaces after the renamed <p> tags. So it seems my error is somewhere in the <template match>?

Comment: It's a separate question now, isn't it? Please add your actual input xml to your question first.

Comment: Code added to original question.

Comment: See the updated solution - what you're looking for can be achieved with ```exclude-result-prefixes```

Comment: @user3783403 Why do you declare all those namespaces when you don't use them **and** don't want them in your output? AFAICT, the only namespace you actually use is `xmlns:prism`.

Comment: I'll be using <dc> and <prism>. But you're right, strip it down to basics. I appreciate all the help above, michael and lagivan. the <prism:issn> now has the namespace declaration added after it, is there a piece of code I'm missing that should skip that? I just want <prism:issn> and </prism:issn>

Comment: @user3783403 the namespace must be declared somewhere - either in <prism:issn> or in any other parent element. Usually the namespace declaration is added to the root element. This should be done explicitly if needed.

Comment: If i declare the namespace at root + in the match, it applies the entire NS declaration to the transformed node?
     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="PGC">
        <prism:pageCount>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </prism:pageCount>
    </xsl:template>    
    <xsl:template match="@PGC">
        <xsl:attribute name="prism:pageCount">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: You don't need to declare the namespace twice, it's enough if you declare it once in the root tag. See the update in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. now the NS declaration eg  xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.2/"  appears before any element with prism: before it?